# how to select and sum both in subquery and query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

I want to sum all the logs. Each log has a facility_id, card_id, and login date. I join table `logs` with table `members` to calculate the age and gender.

The table I want:

[image]

However, the returned value from the query is wrong. I have two other logs with the same card_id and they have a different facility_id. So I should have another record in gender_age_category, but it is not present.

My logs table when joined with members returns more records:

[image]

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) >= 18 AND m.gender = 'female' THEN 'f>17'
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) >= 18 AND m.gender = 'male' THEN 'm>17'
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) < 18 AND m.gender = 'female' THEN 'f<18'
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(current_date, m.birthdate)) < 18 AND m.gender = 'male' THEN 'm<18' 
        END AS gender_age_category,
    mlcs.facility_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(mlc.total),0) AS total,
    COALESCE(SUM(mlc.general), 0) AS general,
    COALESCE(SUM(mlc.course), 0) AS course, 
    COALESCE(SUM(mlc.club), 0) AS club 
FROM
    members m
LEFT JOIN
    total_member_log_counts mlcs ON mlcs.tc_no = m.tc_no
LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT
         tc_no, 
         facility_id,
         COALESCE(SUM(total),0) AS total,
         COALESCE(SUM(general), 0) AS general,
         COALESCE(SUM(course), 0) AS course,
         COALESCE(SUM(club), 0) AS club 
     FROM 
         total_member_log_counts
     GROUP BY
         tc_no, facility_id
    ) as mlc ON mlc.tc_no = m.tc_no
GROUP BY
    gender_age_category,
    mlcs.facility_id
ORDER BY gender_age_category ASC;
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I show the value for each facility as in the second table but by gender and age?

Comment: Please don't use images (as they are uncopiable) - add all relevant information to your question as editable text. Please also update your question with 1) table definitions 2) sample data 3) the result you want to achieve based on that sample data

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre]

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that you get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: remove the row_number function and try if it works